# Will Allah forgive this sin of mine?

Tags: allah

There are a lots of husband who makes their wife pregnant but during pregnancy they don’t even look at their wife. They don’t take care of their wives. I just asked Allah to make those women divorce their husband. It’s been a year i asked this wish. But now i feel guilty for wishing someone's divorce. Will Allah ever forgive me?

Comment: Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful."(39:53)

Answer (score 0):

It is a critical issue of the Muslim society that they don't realize the meaning of Nikah and the rights of husbands and wives.
The husband should take care of his wife, either the wife is pregnant or not.
Now coming to your question about forgiving the sin, if a Momin commits any sin and then regret himself about his sin, then he should make Taubah and promise to Allah that he will not repeat the mistake in the future. In Sha Allah.

Comment: I am an unmarried woman. I am afraid that i will go though a divorce. I am getting restless because of this. I didn’t have any evil intention behind it. I just though those women deserves better man who will take care of them in their difficulty rather than neglecting them. Specially in their pregnancy.